# Rails Devise redirect after User edits their password

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am trying to change the path after the user changes his password following the guide on the devise documentation: [Customize-the-redirect-after-a-user-edits-their-profile](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Customize-the-redirect-after-a-user-edits-their-profile)

Right now, I know that I have to create my own RegistrationController like

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  protected
  def after_update_path_for(resource)
    user_path(resource)
  end
end
```

and change the path to

```
def after_update_path_for(resource)
  dashboard_path
end
```

I created the Registration Model with

```
rails g controller Registrations
```

and moved it to the app/controllers folder

Now it says that I should also configure the routes like

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registrations => :registrations }
```

I am not really familiar with writing routes like that since I only use resources:, so i tried

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registrations => 'dashboard#show' }
```

which gave me the error:

```
'dashboards#show' is not a supported controller name. This can lead to potential routing problems.
```

I don't quite know how I should write the routes correctly in order to change the path to dashboard_path.

Do I even generate my controller correctly?

Comment: I think you should just follow the documentation. it says:
`devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registrations => CONTROLLER_NAME }` not `devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registrations => CONTROLLER_NAME + ACTION_NAME }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `redirect_to root_path` and define the root in your ~/config/routes.rb.

You can define the root path by typing `root 'dashboard#show'` (or more conventionally) `root 'dashboard#index'`.